# How can I get access to my Ribbontabs?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

How Can I get access to my Ribbontabs? I have got 4 tabs and I want to add different buttons in each tab. How I can do ? Because the way I have now I am hidding buttons of other tabs, but I dont think this is the right way. There must be something that I am missing.
Please Help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just place buttons on each ribbon tab, no?